# Uniform icons in .core

Tags: c#, html, css, .net-core, icons

I'm working on a project with many people. We are using a bought canvas scheme which has icons.

We using them e.g.:

```
<div class="style-msg infomsg">
  <div class="sb-msg">
    <i class="icon-info-sign"></i>
    Sign in info message
  </div>
</div>
```

or:

```
<button type="submit" class="button button-3d button-rounded button-green noleftmargin">
    <i class="icon-check"></i>
    Finalize
</button>
```

I want to achieve an uniform icon using with a single icon container.

Can I do this somehow? e.g.:

```
<button type="submit" class="button button-3d button-rounded button-green noleftmargin">
    @Icons.Check
    Finalize
</button>
```

I started something like this:

```
public static class Icons
{
    private static readonly string i = @"<i class=""icon-check""></i>";

    public static IHtmlContent Helper(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return htmlHelper.Raw(i);
    }

    public static IHtmlContent Check => Helper();
}
```

Can anybody help me please?

**UPDATE**:

It can be useful?

```
private static readonly string i = @"<i class=""icon-check""></i>";

public static HtmlString Check => new HtmlString(i);
```